# List<int>.Contains) may not be used in setup / verification expressions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I want Mock a method  but my method is in Condition and I need the value be true and this operation make my test pass if I dont mock my method its give me null exception so it important
this is my **test**

```
  [Test]
    public void Can_return_price_according_to_semester_status()
    {
        var product = new Product
        {
            ProductTypeId = 15,
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Product name 1",
            Price = 12.34M,
            CustomerEntersPrice = false,
            Published = true,
            PreRegistrationPrice = 10.99M
        };

        _productService.Setup(x => x.GetSemesterProductTypeIds(It.IsAny<int[]>())
        .Contains(product.ProductTypeId)).Returns(true);// this is my target mock



        var customer = new Customer();
        _priceCalcService.GetFinalPrice(product, customer, 0, false, 1).ShouldEqual(product.Price);
        _priceCalcService.GetFinalPrice(product, customer, 0, false, 1).ShouldEqual(product.PreRegistrationPrice);
    }
```

and  **GetFinalPrice**  :

```
    if (_productService.GetSemesterProductTypeIds().Contains(product.ProductTypeId))// this is target of my mock
            {
                if (enrollmentTypeId <= 0)
                {
                    if (product.SemesterStatus == SemesterStatus.PreRegistration)
                    {
                        enrollmentTypeId = (int)EnrollmentType.PreRegistered;
                    }
                }
                if (enrollmentTypeId == (int)EnrollmentType.PreRegistered)
                {
                    price = product.PreRegistrationPrice;
                }
            }// some operation after this
```

**problem**
so if u see i need my condition have true value but i dont know how i send it in mock  ?

Comment: you cant use cointain() in  setup the error is bcos of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense to mock the `GetSemesterProductTypeIds()` call than to mock the `Contains()` method.

As per your example, let `GetSemesterProductTypeIds()` return the product type id of your product to make the `Contains()` call result in true.

```
_productService
    .Setup(x => x.GetSemesterProductTypeIds(It.IsAny<int[]>())
    .Returns(new List<int> { 15 });
```